# Powershell: How to work with unknown properties of an array?

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

I apologize if "Property" is the incorrect term for what I need.

I import an excel with the fine import-excel module

```
    $Path = "c:\it\test.xlsx"
$Users = Import-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName 'Routendruck' -StartColumn 1 -StartRow 3 
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $userSAM = $user.Username
    $user

}
```

In $user I find now this

```
Username                           : njue    
E:\Data\Routendruck\               : r
E:\Data\Routendruck\Wien           : m
```

I know the property "username" and can use it with $userSAM = $user.username.
But I don't know the other properties. I don't know how many there are and what their names are. In this example these are folders with read (r) or modify (m) rights that key users can add to an excel sheet and the IT then sets it. I want to automate this.

What I need: to get each property name (eg "E:\Data\Routendruck\Wien") in each $user (they are them same for each $users, since they represent the columns of the excel file). Best all of them in an array. So I can then loop through them with $user.E:\Data\Routendruck\Wien and get their values.

Example

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$property="E:\Data\Routendruck\"

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$property
E:\Data\Routendruck\

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$user.$property
r
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Try with `$Users[0].PsObject.Properties.Name`

Comment: That worked, thank you :) I can loop through this and get the information I need.